# Android Master Detail Fragment Animations Not Working

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am currently working with the Tablet part of my application that implements a Master-Detail structure. When I click buttons in the detail portion of the app, the app transitions to the fragment that I want but not with the animation that I want. It simply replaces the fragment without any animation whatsoever. Note: I am running this app on a Tablet emulator provided by eclipse.

I am using this following code to implement the fragment transaction animation, the same code that I see all over the internet as the RIGHT way to do it:

```
TipContainerFragment fragment = new TipContainerFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
transaction.replace(R.id.skill_detail_container, fragment);

transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

I currently have this code in the SkillListActivity which is the main activity that manages both the master and the detail part of the app. I have tried putting it in the specific fragment (detail) part but I get the same result: the fragment transaction is successful but still with no animation. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: another note: I just need the fragment transaction animation to take place in the detail portion of my app if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out,R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);` for both the new fragment and the fragment which you are replacing.

The 3rd and 4th arguments are for animations which apply when you add/remove fragments from the backstack.

The 1st and 2nd apply when you dont add fragments to the back stack.

In your case you are adding fragment to the back stack but not providing the back stack animations, i.e the 3rd and 4th fragment

Comment: tried this a while ago before you answered and it worked nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are using the v4 Support or APK below 3, this might help (in res/anim/abc_fade_in):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="300" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="200" />

</set>
```